# Replace leading digits with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
s= '<file_name>857173423PARAMOUNT_FUNERAL_IN_BERLIN_AUDIO.mov'
```

How I want to remove all leading digits (if there are four or more consecutive digits) that occur after the string `file_name>`.

So far I have:

```
>>> re.sub('\d+','', s)
'<file_name>PARAMOUNT_FUNERAL_IN_BERLIN_AUDIO.mov'
```

But this of course is not general enough to cover such cases as:

```
s = '<file_name>12897878LIONSGATE_T2.mov'
```

Comment: So *what does what you have do?!*

Comment: Also, don't forget that not everything is solvable by regexps.

Comment: I'm really confused as why this is marked unclear, I've seen much more unclear answers. Not to mention OP gave examples of what he's tried and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Either use a lookbehind](http://regex101.com/r/aF3bR7):

```
(?<=<file_name>)\d+
```

[Or use a capture group and reference it in your substitution](http://regex101.com/r/hB2eW7):

```
(<file_name>)\d+
\1
```

---

I just saw "4 or more digits", you can [replace `+` with `{4,}`](http://regex101.com/r/rV9eG3).  This will match 4+ digits, and by default regex is "greedy" and will continue on and match all of your leading digits:

```
(?<=<file_name>)\d{4,}
```

Comment: Seems pretty self explanatory, and the links should help.  Feel free to ask if you have any questions/problems.

Comment: ^ Yes it is, OP wants to remove only leading digits (i.e. right after `<file_name>`). `_90210` will stay unaffected.

Comment: Thanks, Sam. This answers my question.